# Google Cloud function invoking AWS Lambda function causes "Error: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda."

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to invoke an AWS lambda function `myFunc` from my google cloud function `function1`. Testing `function1` returns

```
Error: function crashed. Details:
The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda.
```

my google function's `index.js`

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk')

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'key',
  secretAccessKey: 'secret',
  region: 'region'
})

let lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.helloWorld = async(event) => {
  let params = {
    FunctionName: 'myFunc',
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    Payload: '{"foo": "bar"}
  }

  return await lambda.invoke(params, function(e,d) {
    if (e){throw e}
    else {return data.Payload}
  }).promise()
}
```

my lambda function has a basic role (`arn:aws:iam::account_number:role/myFunc-role-uu29d`) with `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` managed policy and custom policy for DynamoDB read/write access.

My Trust Relationship looks like this

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: if you change the invocationType to "Event" from "RequestResponse" does it work?
I'm having the same issue from lambda to lambda

Comment: I actually found out that I did not assign a role to my lambda function to read/write from DynamoDB.

Comment: Does it work after role assignment?

Comment: Yes, it does. For clarity, I assigned a custome role via drop down menu in aws.amazon.com --> lambda GUI.